# Phonegap webintent

Tags: cordova

I have to send email using webintent in phonegap for android.I am getting error in the following code.I dont understand how to call the function in script in the index.html file.I am getting json exception.Can anybdy help me to solve this??

WebIntent.java

```
  public class WebIntent extends Plugin {

        private String onNewIntentCallback = null;
        private static final String TAG = "Webintent";


        public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
            Log.d(TAG, "WebintentPlugin Called");
            try {

                  System.out.println("JSON11"+args);
                if (action.equals("startActivity")) {
                    if (args.length() != 1) {
                        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
                    }


                    // Parse the arguments

                    JSONObject obj = args.getJSONObject(0);

                    String type = obj.has("type") ? obj.getString("type") : null;
                    Uri uri = obj.has("url") ? Uri.parse(obj.getString("url")) : null;
                    JSONObject extras = obj.has("extras") ? obj.getJSONObject("extras") : null;
                    Map<String, String> extrasMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // Populate the extras if any exist
                    if (extras != null) {
                        JSONArray extraNames = extras.names();
                        for (int i = 0; i < extraNames.length(); i++) {
                            String key = extraNames.getString(i);
                            String value = extras.getString(key);
                            extrasMap.put(key, value);
                        }
                    }

                    startActivity(obj.getString("action"), uri, type, extrasMap);
                    return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);

                } else if (action.equals("hasExtra")) {
                    if (args.length() != 1) {
                        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
                    }
                    Intent i = ((DroidGap) this.ctx).getIntent();
                    String extraName = args.getString(0);
                    return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, i.hasExtra(extraName));

                } else if (action.equals("getExtra")) {
                    if (args.length() != 1) {
                        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
                    }
                    Intent i = ((DroidGap) this.ctx).getIntent();
                    String extraName = args.getString(0);
                    if (i.hasExtra(extraName)) {
                        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, i.getStringExtra(extraName));
                    } else {
                        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR);
                    }
                } else if (action.equals("getUri")) {
                    if (args.length() != 0) {
                        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
                    }

                    Intent i = ((DroidGap) this.ctx).getIntent();
                    String uri = i.getDataString();
                    return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, uri);
                } else if (action.equals("onNewIntent")) {
                    if (args.length() != 0) {
                        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
                    }

                    this.onNewIntentCallback = callbackId;
                    PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
                    result.setKeepCallback(true);
                    return result;
                } else if (action.equals("sendBroadcast")) 
                {
                    if (args.length() != 1) {
                        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
                    }

                    // Parse the arguments
                    JSONObject obj = args.getJSONObject(0);
                    System.out.println("JSON"+obj);
                    JSONObject extras = obj.has("extras") ? obj.getJSONObject("extras") : null;
                    Map<String, String> extrasMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // Populate the extras if any exist
                    if (extras != null) {
                        JSONArray extraNames = extras.names();
                        for (int i = 0; i < extraNames.length(); i++) {
                            String key = extraNames.getString(i);
                            String value = extras.getString(key);
                            extrasMap.put(key, value);
                        }
                    }

                    sendBroadcast(obj.getString("action"), extrasMap);
                    return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
                }
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            if (this.onNewIntentCallback != null) {
                PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, intent.getDataString());
                result.setKeepCallback(true);
                this.success(result, this.onNewIntentCallback);
            }
        }

        void startActivity(String action, Uri uri, String type, Map<String, String> extras) {
            Intent i = (uri != null ? new Intent(action, uri) : new Intent(action));

            if (type != null && uri != null) {
                i.setDataAndType(uri, type); //Fix the crash problem with android 2.3.6
            } else {
                if (type != null) {
                    i.setType(type);
                }
            }

            for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
                String value = extras.get(key);
                // If type is text html, the extra text must sent as HTML
                if (key.equals(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT) && type.equals("text/html")) {
                    i.putExtra(key, Html.fromHtml(value));
                } else if (key.equals(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
                    // allowes sharing of images as attachments.
                    // value in this case should be a URI of a file
                    i.putExtra(key, Uri.parse(value));
                } else if (key.equals(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL)) {
                    // allows to add the email address of the receiver
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"myemail.com"});
                } else {
                    i.putExtra(key, value);
                }
            }
            this.ctx.startActivity(i);
        }

        void sendBroadcast(String action, Map<String, String> extras) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(action);
            for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
                String value = extras.get(key);
                intent.putExtra(key, value);
            }



            ((DroidGap) this.ctx).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
webintent.js

    var WebIntent = function() { 

    };

    WebIntent.ACTION_SEND = "android.intent.action.SEND";
    WebIntent.ACTION_VIEW= "android.intent.action.VIEW";
    WebIntent.EXTRA_TEXT = "android.intent.extra.TEXT";
    WebIntent.EXTRA_SUBJECT = "android.intent.extra.SUBJECT";
    WebIntent.EXTRA_STREAM = "android.intent.extra.STREAM";
    WebIntent.EXTRA_EMAIL = "android.intent.extra.EMAIL";

    WebIntent.prototype.startActivity = function(params, success, fail) {
        return cordova.exec(function(args) {
            success(args);
        }, function(args) {
            fail(args);
        }, 'WebIntent', 'startActivity', [params]);
    };

    WebIntent.prototype.hasExtra = function(params, success, fail) {
        return cordova.exec(function(args) {
            success(args);
        }, function(args) {
            fail(args);
        }, 'WebIntent', 'hasExtra', [params]);
    };

    WebIntent.prototype.getUri = function(success, fail) {
        return cordova.exec(function(args) {
            success(args);
        }, function(args) {
            fail(args);
        }, 'WebIntent', 'getUri', []);
    };

    WebIntent.prototype.getExtra = function(params, success, fail) {
        return cordova.exec(function(args) {
            success(args);
        }, function(args) {
            fail(args);
        }, 'WebIntent', 'getExtra', [params]);
    };


    WebIntent.prototype.onNewIntent = function(callback) {
        return cordova.exec(function(args) {
            callback(args);
        }, function(args) {
        }, 'WebIntent', 'onNewIntent', []);
    };

    WebIntent.prototype.sendBroadcast = function(params, success, fail) {
        return cordova.exec(function(args) {
            success(args);
        }, function(args) {
            fail(args);
        }, 'WebIntent', 'sendBroadcast', [params]);
    };



    cordova.addConstructor(function() {
        cordova.addPlugin('WebIntent', new WebIntent());
    });

index.html

<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=low-dpi; user-scalable=no" />
    <title>PhoneGap Events Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.0.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="webintent.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


         function onBodyLoad()
         {
         document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
        }

   function onDeviceReady() {    
       window.plugins.WebIntent.startActivity('WebIntent', success, fail);

        }
        function success(e) {


        console.log("Success");
        }

        function fail(f) {
             console.log("Failure");
        }





    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onBodyLoad();">
    <h2>IMEI v1.5</h2>
    IMEI: <span id="imei"></span><br/>

  </body>
</html>


My error is-

07-10 10:23:12.180: W/System.err(536): org.json.JSONException: Value WebIntent at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-10 10:23:12.200: W/System.err(536):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
07-10 10:23:12.200: W/System.err(536):  at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:484)
07-10 10:23:12.230: W/System.err(536):  at com.gsr.imei.WebIntent.execute(WebIntent.java:48)
07-10 10:23:12.240: W/System.err(536):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:186)
07-10 10:23:12.240: W/System.err(536):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)


can anyone help me??Thanks for any help..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.plugins.WebIntent.startActivity('WebIntent', success, fail);
```

Should be a map object like this:

```
window.plugins.WebIntent.startActivity({url: 'url here', type: 'type', extras: {}}, success, fail);
```

### Edit

Using this function to call the intent

```
function sendEmail(to, subject, body) { 
          var extras = {};
          extras[WebIntent.EXTRA_SUBJECT] = subject;
          extras[WebIntent.EXTRA_TEXT] = body;
          window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
              url: to,
              action: WebIntent.ACTION_SEND,
              type: 'text/plain', 
              extras: extras 
            }, 
            function() {
                alert("mail sent");
            }, 
            function() {
              alert('Failed to send email via Android Intent');
            }
          ); 
    }
```

It opens up the mail send dialog with all the sent parameter.

Comment: I tried with this..I am not getting any error but the email is not sent.it is showing fail msg.

Comment: i have not used this plugin as such, you should put the error log

Comment: i tested the code and it sends the mail fine, i have put my method in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the json.js file in your project? 
Pls check, I also got the same issue and it got resolved after including the json.js file.