# Email send with WebIntent plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying WebIntent plugin to send email, but failed to send. Can you give me a complete example to send Email with WebIntent with Android.

I have also found that stackoverflow link
[Phonegap webintent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406917/phonegap-webintent)

After followed this, when I click to send button it show a option to select how I like to send email. Then I select my app name from options, and then I find 'unfortunately app_name is stopped'.

Any help?

-Arefin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the ACTION_SEND to send emails from Android Devices. I show you one example to send an email:

```
Button btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //obtenemos los datos para el envío del correo 
        EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        EditText etSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSubject);
        EditText etBody = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBody);
        CheckBox chkAttachment = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkAttachment);
        Intent itSend = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        itSend.setType("plain/text");
        itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ etEmail.getText().toString()});
        itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, etSubject.getText().toString());
        itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, etBody.getText());

        if (chkAttachment.isChecked()) {
            itSend.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.icon));

            itSend.setType("image/png");
        }

        startActivity(itSend);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but your code is native Android sdk. I was talking with PhoneGap plugin for sending email in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inappBrowser from Cordova to make a intent https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

i used the Webintent Plugin first, but iam not pleased about(Only for android and very slow), therfore i use the inappbrowser.

Example for Email "Webintent":

```
var strMailUriFormat= "mailto:<Mail>?subject=<Subject>&body=<BodyContent>  
window.open(strMailUriFormat,"_system","location=no");
```

it works for iOS and other OS to. And you can make other intents to like "tel" etc.

have fun!